# Induction hypothesis for inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The solution to a question I found online is in the image below, I'm confused on how did they go from $2^n + 2$ to$ 2^n + 2^n$. Where did they get the extra $2^n$ from? and then they got $2^{n+1}$ from $2^n + 2^n$. It's not multiplication so how did they get $2^{(n+1)}$ suddenly?

---

Prove that for all integers $n \geq 4,$ we have:
(a) $2 n+1<2^{n}$
Solution. We prove it by induction on $n .$ For $n=4,$ we have $2 \cdot 4+1=9<1$
Now, assume that $2 n+1<2^{n}$. Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
2(n+1)+1 &=2 n+1+2 \\
&<2^{n}+2
\end{aligned} \quad \begin{array}{l}
\text { [by the IH }]
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
<2^{n}+2^{n} & {\left[\text { as } n \geq 4,2^{n}>2\right]} \\
=2^{n+1}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

You can as well prove the inductive step by using strong induction twice. Assume the hypothesis holds for $\frac{1}{2}n$, then we must prove it holds for $n$.
$$ 2\left(\frac{1}{2}n\right) + 1 < 2^{\frac{1}{2}n}$$
$$ n + 1 < 2^{\frac{1}{2}n}$$
Multiply both sides by $2$ so we get:
$$ 2n + 2 < 2^{\frac{1}{2}n} \cdot 2 $$
$$ 2n + 1 < 2n + 2 < 2^{\frac{1}{2}n + 1} $$
All we have to prove now is that $\frac{1}{2}n + 1 < n$ for $n >=4$. Again we prove this using strong induction.

To prove that $$\frac{1}{2}n + 1 < n$$
When $n=4$:
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 + 1 = 2 < 4$$
In the inductive step, assume the statement holds for $\frac{1}{2}n$, then prove it holds for $n$.

$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}n\right) + 1 < \frac{1}{2}n $$
Now multiply both sides by $2$.
$$ 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}n\right) + 2 \cdot 1 < 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}n$$
$$ \frac{1}{2}n + 1 < \frac{1}{2}n + 2 < n $$
$$ \frac{1}{2}n + 1 < n $$
And we are done. (QED)

We used the same approach twice to prove both the original statement and the nested statement. A bit of a recursive proof really. I like to call this approach of repetitive induction Gilbert's Idea of Nested Strong induction (GINS). It might look long right now but remember it when you have to prove something a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge4$, $2<2^n$, so $2^n+2<2^n+2^n$,

and $2^n+2^n=2\cdot2^n=2^{n+1}$.

Comment: I'm confused on the part after the and. how did you go from 2^n + 2^n = 2 ⋅ 2^n ?

Comment: Let $x=2^n$.  Then apply $x+x=2\cdot x$

Comment: oh I'm so dumb. It's like saying 4+4 is 4x2. it's just double. thank you I missed that